# Правильно ли говорить "затруднились с ответом"?

Tags: правила

"n% затруднились с ответом"... СМИ регулярно используют это выражение в соц. опросах. Правильно ли это выражение с точки зрения правил русского языка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это выражение правильно.

Из толкового словаря

ЗАТРУДНИТЬСЯ

1. в чём, с чем и (устар.) чем или с инф. Испытать затруднение, неудобство, неловкость; обремениться чем-л. **З. с ответом.** З. сказать правду. З. в выборе кадров.
2. Стать более трудным, усложниться чем-л. С наступлением сумерек продвижение затруднилось.